# Get filename of a message opened in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

How can I get the actual file name of a message (as it is stored on my disk) opened with mu4e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the current message the active cursor is in
`(plist-get (mu4e-message-at-point) :path)`.

Comment: Thanks. For future readers: You can use `(kill-new (plist-get (mu4e-message-at-point) :path))` to copy the path to clipboard.